# Validation plugin - Auto validate multiple forms on a page

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Currently I need to validate every form like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#admin_settings_general').validate({
            rules: {
                admin_settings_application_title: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            },
            unhighlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            }
        });
    });
```

I want that it automaticly validate the forms for every element with the `required`  tag.

How can I do that?

Comment: _"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results**. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)."_

Comment: How do you mean "automatically"? The Validate plugin already automatically validates every element with a `required` attribute. And if you mean without having to call `.validate()`, you can't... that's the _intialization_ method of the plugin. How else is it supposed to know which form to validate and what options to use?

Comment: Well, i mean i have to call `$('#admin_settings_general').validate()` for each of the forms currently. How can i call it without limiting it to one form?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: `$.validate()` but then it does not validate the forms.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> "*I want that it automaticly validate the forms for every element with the required tag."*

**Quote OP comment:**

> *"i have to call `$('#admin_settings_general').validate()` for each of the forms currently. How can i call it without limiting it to one form?"*

---

To properly initialize `.validate()` on *all* forms on a page, use a common selector such as the `form` tag itself (or a `class`).   Since you cannot attach `.validate()` to **any** jQuery selector that represents multiple `form` elements, use a jQuery `.each()`.  This is simply how this plugins methods were designed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('form').each(function() {  // attach to all form elements on page
        $(this).validate({       // initialize plugin on each form
            // global options for plugin
        });
    });

});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/6Fs9y/**

Comment: @Michael, fixed typo and added demo.  You're welcome.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me.  Note that you need the ``each`` call.  Calling ``validate()`` on ``$("form")`` is not enough; you need to individually call ``validate()`` on each instance of ``form``.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/6Fs9y/86/ why this method is work. Multiple selector ........?

Comment: @PrashantTapase, you should not post new questions as comments.  However, you cannot attach the `.validate()` method to **any** jQuery selector that represents more than one form, because that's just how the developer designed his plugin.  Use an `.each()` as explained in my answer:  http://jsfiddle.net/6Fs9y/87/

Comment: Actually, this is official solution.
See http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-validating-multiple-forms-on-one-page

Comment: @Sparky Yes, my comment is to confirm your answer