# Forms in modal submit with same action (same PHP file)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have two different forms embedded in two different Bootstrap modals. They are being called correctly and loaded correctly. I can see that each form (in the source of the page) has the right action assigned to it. Doing a bit of detective work, I discovered that no matter how many modals with forms I have, they all submit to the same action/form, which is the one that comes first in my code.

Clearly, I'm not closing something correctly or have duplicate IDs or something, but I can't figure out what's causing the problem. Here are two of the forms. If I only load up one or the other, each works fine. If I load up both, then both forms submit the the action in the first form.

Of note, I have another form that's not in a modal that always works fine and comes before both of these other forms in my code.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="get_started-complete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style=" overflow: scroll; height:auto;">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Getting Started</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              some text here
              <form class="form form-quote dark" id="form_1" action="get_started_1.php" method="post" style="margin-top:5px;">
                <div class="form-group" style="line-height:0px;">
                  <label  style="line-height:25px;" for="fullname_1" class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Full Name</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" style=" margin-top: 5px;" class="form-control" name="fullname_1" id="fullname_1" placeholder="">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="line-height:0px;">
                  <label  style="line-height:25px;" for="company_name_1" class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Company Name</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" style=" margin-top: 5px;" class="form-control" name="company_name_1" id="company_name_1" placeholder="">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="line-height:0px;">
                  <label style="line-height:25px;" for="email_1" class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Email Address</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="email" style=" margin-top: 5px;" class="form-control required email" name="email_1" id="email_1" placeholder="">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="line-height:0px;">
                  <label style="line-height:25px;" for="database_size_1" class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Database Size</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" style=" margin-top: 5px;" class="form-control" name="database_size_1" id="database_size_1" placeholder="Enter a number">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <div id="recap4"></div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="form_location" id="form_location" value="complete" hidden>
                <button type="submit" id="get_started_submitted-c" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit Form</button>
                (Click once and give it a second or two...)
              </form>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--FORM 2-->
       <div class="modal fade" id="get_started-advanced" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style=" overflow: scroll; height:auto;">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Getting Started</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              some text here
              <form class="form form-quote dark" id="form_2" action="get_started_2.php" method="post" style="margin-top:5px;">
                <div class="form-group" style="line-height:0px;">
                  <label  style="line-height:25px;" for="fullname_2" class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Full Name</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" style=" margin-top: 5px;" class="form-control" name="fullname_2" id="fullname_2" placeholder="">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="line-height:0px;">
                  <label  style="line-height:25px;" for="company_name_2" class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Company Name</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" style=" margin-top: 5px;" class="form-control" name="company_name_2" id="company_name_2" placeholder="">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="line-height:0px;">
                  <label style="line-height:25px;" for="email_2" class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Email Address</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="email" style=" margin-top: 5px;" class="form-control required email" name="email_2" id="email_2" placeholder="">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="line-height:0px;">
                  <label style="line-height:25px;" for="database_size_2" class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Database Size</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" style=" margin-top: 5px;" class="form-control" name="database_size_2" id="database_size_2" placeholder="Enter a number">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <div id="recap3"></div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="form_location_2" id="form_location_2" value="advanced" hidden>
                <button type="submit" id="get_started_submitted-a" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit Form</button>
                (Click once and give it a second or two...)
              </form>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Theory that my submit handler is causing the problem. Here is what that looks like:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
      var $this = $(form);
      $.ajax({
        url: $this.attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: $this.serialize(),
      })
      .done(function(msg) {
        if( msg == 'ok' ) {
          toastr.success('Thank you. We will be in touch within 24 hours.');
          $this[0].reset();

        } else {
          toastr.error('Sorry. An error occured. Please try again later or email us directly ');
        }
      })
      .fail(function() {
        toastr.error('An error occured. Please try again later or email us directly .');
      });
    }
```

Comment: Is there a submit handler that is submitting via ajax? Or are these default browser submits?

Comment: @charlietfl I'm really not sure. How would I check this?

Comment: does page reload or do you see a request made in browser dev tools network

Comment: @charlietfl The page doesn't reload. I see the request in the dev tools.

Comment: problem then is in the submit handling javascript. My guess is it's getting the url from first form `action`

Comment: @okay...why would it take from the `action` in the code for the first modal within the code though?

Comment: @charlietfl I added the code for my `submithandler` to my question, but not sure if this is the problme

Comment: Depends how it is written. It's not going to be part of bootstrap or modal code

Comment: looks like validate plugin code...what is the selector used for plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the validate() plugin doesn't work well when calling multiple forms in one selector.

Try initializing this way:

```
$('form.form-quote').each(function(){
     $(this).validate({ /* options */}); 

});
```

Should isolate instances better

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19209548/1175966