# Validate 3 forms in one php page using one jquery file

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation

I have 3 forms in same php page. Each form contain same input fields (with different names) Also the action of each form after submitting is different. One is for inserting new record in db another is for updating same record and last one is form is for deleting that record.

I want to validate all of them in one jquery script. So, I did this:

Form:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<!-- jQuery Validation Plugin 
hosted by Google API -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){  

    $('#showadd').click(function() {
                $('.add').toggle("slide");
                $('.update').hide();
                $('.delete').hide();
        });

    $('#showupdate').click(function() {
                $('.update').toggle("slide");
                $('.add').hide();
                $('.delete').hide();
        });

    $('#showdelete').click(function() {
                $('.delete').toggle("slide");
                $('.update').hide();
                $('.add').hide();
        });

    $('input.text').keyup(function () {
        $('input.link').prop('disabled', this.value.length === 0 ? false : true);
        $('input.evidence').prop('disabled', this.value.length === 0 ? false : true);
    });

    $('input.link').keyup(function () {
        $('input.text').prop('disabled', this.value.length === 0 ? false : true);
        $('input.evidence').prop('disabled', this.value.length === 0 ? false : true);
    });

    $(".evidence").on("change", function(){
          if($.trim($(".evidence").val())){
            $('.link').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('.text').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }else{$('.link').removeAttr('disabled');$('.text').removeAttr('disabled');}
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="showadd">Add Evidence</div>
    <br>
    <div class="add" style="display:none">
      <form action="institutionLevel.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="inst-form" novalidate>
          <div class="formLayout">
          <div class="required">
          <label>Evidence Category</label>
          <select name="category">
          <option value="none"></option>
          <option value="Mission Goals and Objectives">Mission, Goals and Objectives</option>
          <option value="Governance and Administration">Governance and Administration</option>
          <option value="Management of Quality Assurance and Improvement">Management of Quality Assurance and Improvement</option>
          <option value="Learning and Teaching">Learning and Teaching</option>
          <option value="Student Administration and Support Services">Student Administration and Support Services</option>
          <option value="Learning Resources">Learning Resources</option>
          <option value="Facilities and Equipment">Facilities and Equipment</option>
          <option value="Financial Planning and Management">Financial Planning and Management</option>
          <option value="Employment Processes">Employment Processes</option>
          <option value="Research">Research</option>
          <option value="Relationships with the Community">Relationships with the Community</option>
          </select>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="required">
            <label>Evidence Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title"/>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="required">
          <label>Evidence File</label>
          <input type="file"  name="evidence" id="evidenceToUpload" class="evidence"> 
          <label id="evidenceSize"></label> 
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="required">
          <label>Evidence Link</label>
          <input type="text" name="eviLink" class="link"/>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="required">
          <label>Physical Evidence</label>
          <input type="text" name="eviText" class="text"/>
          </div>
          <br>
        <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" class="styled_button"/>
         </div>
      </form>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div id="showupdate">Update Evidence</div>
    <br>
    <div class="update" style="display:none">
      <form action="institutionLevel.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="inst-form" novalidate>
          <div class="formLayout">
          <div class="required">
          <label>Evidence Category</label>
          <select name="category_update">
          <option value="none"></option>
          <option value="Mission Goals and Objectives">Mission, Goals and Objectives</option>
          <option value="Governance and Administration">Governance and Administration</option>
          <option value="Management of Quality Assurance and Improvement">Management of Quality Assurance and Improvement</option>
          <option value="Learning and Teaching">Learning and Teaching</option>
          <option value="Student Administration and Support Services">Student Administration and Support Services</option>
          <option value="Learning Resources">Learning Resources</option>
          <option value="Facilities and Equipment">Facilities and Equipment</option>
          <option value="Financial Planning and Management">Financial Planning and Management</option>
          <option value="Employment Processes">Employment Processes</option>
          <option value="Research">Research</option>
          <option value="Relationships with the Community">Relationships with the Community</option>
          </select>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="required">
            <label>Evidence Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title_update"/>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="required">
          <label>Evidence File</label>
          <input type="file"  name="evidence_update" id="evidenceToUpload_update" class="evidence"> 
          <label id="evidenceSizeUpdate"></label> 
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="required">
          <label>Evidence Link</label>
          <input type="text" name="eviLink_update" class="link"/>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="required">
          <label>Physical Evidence</label>
          <input type="text" name="eviText_update" class="text"/>
          </div>
          <br>
        <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" class="styled_button"/>
         </div>
      </form>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div id="showdelete">Delete Evidence</div>
    <br>
    <div class="delete" style="display:none">
      <form action="institutionLevel.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="inst-form" novalidate>
          <div class="formLayout">
          <div class="required">
          <label>Evidence Category</label>
          <select name="category_delete">
          <option value="none"></option>
          <option value="Mission Goals and Objectives">Mission, Goals and Objectives</option>
          <option value="Governance and Administration">Governance and Administration</option>
          <option value="Management of Quality Assurance and Improvement">Management of Quality Assurance and Improvement</option>
          <option value="Learning and Teaching">Learning and Teaching</option>
          <option value="Student Administration and Support Services">Student Administration and Support Services</option>
          <option value="Learning Resources">Learning Resources</option>
          <option value="Facilities and Equipment">Facilities and Equipment</option>
          <option value="Financial Planning and Management">Financial Planning and Management</option>
          <option value="Employment Processes">Employment Processes</option>
          <option value="Research">Research</option>
          <option value="Relationships with the Community">Relationships with the Community</option>
          </select>
          </div>
          <br>
        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" class="styled_button"/>
         </div>
      </form>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Jquery:

```
// JavaScript Document
//jQuery Form Validation code

(function($,W,D)
{
    var JQUERY4U = {};

    JQUERY4U.UTIL =
    {
        setupFormValidation: function()
        {
            //form validation rules

    // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
    $("#inst-form").validate({
        errorElement: 'div',
        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
            category: 
            {
            checkEviCategory: true,
            },
            title: 
            {
            required: true,
            },
            evidence:
            {
                accept: "pdf",
                required: true,
                checkEvidence: true,
            },
            eviLink:{
                required: true,
            },
            eviText:
            {
            required: true, 
            },

            category_update: 
            {
            checkEviCategory: true,
            },
            title_update: 
            {
            required: true,
            },
            evidence_update:
            {
                accept: "pdf",
                required: true,
                checkEvidenceUpdate: true,
            },
            eviLink_update:{
                required: true,
            },
            eviText_update:
            {
            required: true, 
            },

        },

        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
            title: 
            {
            required: "Enter evidence title",
            },
            EviLink: 
            {
            required: "Enter evidence link",
            },
            EviText: 
            {
            required: "Enter the physical location‬‏ of the evidence",
            },
            evidence:{
            accept: "Upload pdf document only",
            required: "Upload ..",
            },

            title_update: 
            {
            required: "Enter evidence title",
            },
            eviLink_update: 
            {
            required: "Enter evidence link",
            },
            eviText_update: 
            {
            required: "Enter the physical location‬‏ of the evidence",
            },
            evidence_update:{
            accept: "upload pdf document only",
            required: "Upload ..",
            },
            },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
                }
            });

            jQuery.validator.addMethod('checkEviCategory', function (value) {
        return (value != 'none');
    }, "Select evidence category");

jQuery.validator.addMethod('checkEvidence', function () {
    if(!$("#evidenceToUpload").val() == '')
    {   
    var iSize = ($("#evidenceToUpload")[0].files[0].size / 1024); 
     if (iSize / 1024 > 1) 
     { 
        if (((iSize / 1024) / 1024) > 1) 
        { 
            iSize = (Math.round(((iSize / 1024) / 1024) * 100) / 100);
            $("#evidenceSize").html( iSize + " GB"); 
        }
        else
        { 
            iSize = (Math.round((iSize / 1024) * 100) / 100)
            $("#evidenceSize").html( iSize + " MB"); 
        } 
     } 
     else 
     {
        iSize = (Math.round(iSize * 100) / 100)
        $("#evidenceSize").html( iSize  + " KB"); 
     }   
     return (iSize<4294967295);  // 4GB is 4,294,967,295 bytes
    }
    return true;
    }, "File exceeded 4GB");

    jQuery.validator.addMethod('checkEvidenceUpdate', function () {
    if(!$("#evidenceToUpload_update").val() == '')
    {   
    var iSize = ($("#evidenceToUpload_update")[0].files[0].size / 1024); 
     if (iSize / 1024 > 1) 
     { 
        if (((iSize / 1024) / 1024) > 1) 
        { 
            iSize = (Math.round(((iSize / 1024) / 1024) * 100) / 100);
            $("#evidenceSizeUpdate").html( iSize + " GB"); 
        }
        else
        { 
            iSize = (Math.round((iSize / 1024) * 100) / 100)
            $("#evidenceSizeUpdate").html( iSize + " MB"); 
        } 
     } 
     else 
     {
        iSize = (Math.round(iSize * 100) / 100)
        $("#evidenceSizeUpdate").html( iSize  + " KB"); 
     }   
     return (iSize<4294967295);  // 4GB is 4,294,967,295 bytes
    }
    return true;
    }, "File exceeded 4GB");
}}
    //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
    $(D).ready(function($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
    });

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Result:

Only first form is validated !!

How to ***fix*** this in the easiest possible why (with minimum changes).

Also, I'm a beginner at jquery I hate assigning rules and messages dynamically (An answer I found for the same case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID is meant to be unique for each element on a page, change your id to be unique, then you can add a specific class and call off that for the validation, instead of the ID. As long as the class is attached to all 3 forms and the validation is as well then it should work.

eg.

```
    <form action="institutionLevel.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="inst-form" id="form1" novalidate>

   <form action="institutionLevel.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="inst-form" id="form2" novalidate>

   <form action="institutionLevel.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="inst-form" id="form3" novalidate>
```

That is an example of how you would call your forms (obviously not in a row like that) then your validation would be:

```
 $(".inst-form").validate({
```

That might cause issues though, Im not too sure as I haven't tested it.

Comment: I tried this (class="inst-form" insted of id="inst-form"), it didn't work :")

Comment: what is your point of adding id="form1", id="form2" and id="form3" ?

Comment: I guess they aren't needed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208987/validation-plugin-auto-validate-multiple-forms-on-a-page check that page it has your answer to your question

Comment: Its not the answer I need :( the validation has no rules nor custom messages

Comment: If you read the comments it says: However, you cannot attach the .validate() method to any jQuery selector that represents more than one form, because that's just how the developer designed his plugin. Use an .each() as explained in my answer:

Comment: So I have to assign rules and messages dynamically ?

Comment: You can have one set of rules, messages etc just assign them to a var eg: var ruleList = { INSERT RULES}; etc, that will stop alot of double up, then call that on all 3 of your validations. But you can't assign 1 validate on 3 forms.