# JQuery Validator with Virtual Page Views

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i'm making a landing page with some forms on it and i'm using JQuery validator to validate the Input on every form, the thing is that two of the forms should have the same ID and Class, and they are validated through their class as such

```
$('form.contact-1').validate({
```

So there are TWO forms with this class, after you fill the first form then it does a simply show/hide to display the second form which is just an extension of the first form. Then it sends the entire virtual page view to Google Analytics. That's how it should work in Theory, the downside is that when i fill the first form and move to the second, JQuery validator ceases to work.

Is there any way you could achieve this without having to do more seperate validations?

Comment: You absolutely should NOT use the same `id` more than once on the page... that's what `class` is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"...the thing is that two of the forms should have the same ID and Class, and they are validated through their class as such..."*

If you want to initialize the plugin on more than one form on a page, then you'll need to wrap the `.validate()` method with an `.each()`.

```
$('form.contact-1').each(function() {
    $(this).validate({
        // global rules & options for all forms
    });
});
```

[Official Documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-validating-multiple-forms-on-one-page):

> The plugin can handle only one form per call. In case you have multiple forms on a single page which you want to validate, you have to initialise them all individually

---

**IMPORTANT**:  If you indeed are using the same `id` on both forms, then this is **invalid HTML**, so it will be unreliable cross-browser, and any JavaScript could fail or be unpredictable.  If you cannot make each `id` unique, then remove `id` entirely and rely solely on the `class` designation, which was designed to be repeatable.

**Working DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/n9Lup2dy/**

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to troubleshoot without your full codes, but you can try the following method.

```
 $('form').each(function() {  
        $(this).validate({       // initialize plugin on each form
            // global options for plugin
        });
    });
```

answer from [Validation plugin - Auto validate multiple forms on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208987/validation-plugin-auto-validate-multiple-forms-on-a-page)